# How do I get user input without using scanf in a console app?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to allow users to simply hit Enter without typing anything, and use this to mean accepting a default value.  *scanf* isn't doing what I want and the app still 'blocks': **the next line of code doesn't run**.

The only way is to actually type something THEN press Enter.

I tried using *NSFileHandle* and *fileHandleWithStandardInput*; however, it seems that the user is now forced to hit Ctrl-D to indicate *EOF*.

Someone suggested using *fgets*, but I cannot work out what to pass as 3rd parameter (of `FILE*` type). Tried *stdin* but it doesn't 'block'.

How do I accept input from a user, using Objective-C, and at the same time allow the user to simply hit Enter without being forced to type anything?  How do I read a single line, even if that line is blank?

Comment: This question is very much more clear, I think it can stay as is.

Comment: You *might* edit this to be clearer about "How do I correctly call fgets with stdin to do X", **include a test case** (or at least example code), etc.

Comment: Do you mean the code *doesn't* block and the next line runs *immediately*?  If so, you're simply mixing non-line-based with line-based input, and you have a common problem.  (Test cases clear up this kind of issue readily.)

Comment: No, I meant the code 'blocks' (for an input) and next line doesn't run. 
I'm actually trying to get the code to unblock (the input request) and run the next line if the user simply hits Enter.

Comment: Well I could keep on editing the subject constantly but I think the question is clear enough.

Comment: @Riaz: It's really not clear without a test case, and you've given mixed messages.

Comment: To "block" in this context means "to stop execution and wait for input". It has nothing to do what how you deal with the input. A "non-blocking" case would be one where the program continues to do *something* while it waits on the user input (e.g. like `top`, or web browsers either of which keep updating the display while waiting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the code *doesn't* block and the next line runs *immediately* (as you seemed to indicate early in the question and in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311156/#comment-2279261)), you have a common problem when mixing non-line-based and line-based input.

What happens is you have a newline left in the buffer, and fgets sees that, reads it, and returns, instead of doing what you really want: *ignoring* it, and then reading a line.

The solution is to simply do the ignoring part yourself, and then call fgets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE* ignoreline(FILE* stream) {
  for (int c; (c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF;) {
    if (c == '\n') break;
  }
  return stream;
}

void example_use() {
  char buf[1000];
  ignoreline(stdin);
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
  // or, since it returns the stream, can be more compact:
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, ignoreline(stdin));
}

int main() { // error handling omitted
  int n;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  char buf[1000];
  printf("Enter a line: ");
  ignoreline(stdin); // comment this line and compare the difference
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
  *strchr(buf, '\n') = '\0';
  printf("You entered '%s'.\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that it is also common and encouraged to "pair" the ignoreline with the scanf (or other non-line-based input) to turn that into line-based input.  You may want to modify it, in that case, so you can tell the difference between input of "42 abc" and "42" (in the "Enter a number" case).  Some people just use fgets everywhere, then parse that line with sscanf, and while that works, it's not necessary.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks for the help - I tried doing a new project and chuck the test code for stdin/fgets in *main* and it blocks fine.

Comment: @Riaz: FWIW, while I feel your frustration, if this answers your question, then your question is really about C.  I've only used Standard C here and have never coded Obj-C a day in my life. :)

Comment: It's really not fair that I can lambast you for not providing a test case while my example is not fully complete and working (it's so easy to do, and so I have now), but that's life.

Comment: Lambasting is fine by me as long as you provide the answer and save me an hour or two :-) Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I use `getch();` in library `conio.h`
simply the program waits for any key to be pressed

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, you can use the ReadConsoleInput function (see MSDN for more on this) :

```
INPUT_RECORD keyin;
DWORD r;

    while (ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),&keyin,1,&r)) {

    if (keyin.EventType!=KEY_EVENT) continue;
    if (keyin.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode==VK_SPACE) break;    ///use these VK codes to get any key's input

    if (keyin.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode==VK_F1)            
    {
       printf("You pressed F1\n");
    }

    if (keyin.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode==VK_F2)            
    {
        printf("You pressed F2\n",);
    }

    }//end while loop
```

You don't need to hit enter after each key then.This works like a dream for me...

Answer (score 1):

use `getchar()` to take input without using `scanf` function...

Comment: To increase the quality of your post please include how/why your answer will solve the problem.