# Optional parameters in fscanf [C]

Tags: c, scanf

Hello I am struggling with creating my menu for my linked list. I am told to use fscanf to take in input, but I have an argument that the user may not always enter, specifically a number to add to the linked list. The way I have fscanf set up is it reads a char, a number, and then another char (the [enter] key). E.g. the user enters "a 20[enter]" to add the number 20 to the linked list. However, if the user enters "d[enter]", then the num field is invalid because the user entered a char! Note I **cannot** use fgets().

Do I need another fscanf field? Here's my menu code below:

```
int main(void) {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    int num, ret;
    char select = 'n';
    char c;
    while (select != 'e') {
        printf("Enter:\na(dd) (x) = add a new node with value x to the list at the front of the list\n");
        printf("d(el) = delete the first node of list\n");
        printf("l(ength) = print the number of nodes in the list\n");
        printf("p(rint) = print the complete list\n");
        printf("z(ero) = delete the entire list\n");
        printf("e(xit) = quit the program\n");          
        ret = (fscanf(stdin, "%c %d%c", &select, &num, &c));
        if (ret == 3 && select == 'a' && c == '\n')
            Add(&head, num);
        else if (ret == 2 && select == 'd')
            Delete(&head);
        else if (ret == 2 && select == 'l')
            Length(head);
        else if (ret == 2 && select == 'p')
            PrintList(head);
        else if (ret == 2 && select == 'z' )
            ZeroList(&head);
        else
            printf("invalid\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: get the first char with `scanf` and then determine if you need to get a number. Also, can you use `getline()` ?

Comment: No, just fscanf. thanks for the help too, ill try that.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` doesn't have default value for parameters. use `fgets` to read a line ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2311861/2730925) may help you) then use `sscanf` to parse the input. if entered line in `fgets` starts with character `a` then use `sscanf(line,"%c %d %c", &select, &num, &c )` else use `sscanf(line,"%c %c", &select, &c )`.

Comment: %s matches only until the first non-whitespace. oh now that I re-read his question i guess the input doesnt have whitespace like `a20` although he wrote "`a 20`"