# While Loop isn't repeating?

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

This is a homework question.  I am taking a C programming class.  The requirement that I am working with now is

"If an empty message is entered, the user should be prompted to enter a non-empty message until they enter one which is at least 1 character long."

This is the code I have now:

```
int main(void)
{
char string[101];
int menu;

do
{
    printf("Enter a text message (maximum 100 characters long) : ");
    scanf(" %100[^\n]s", string);
}
while (string[0] == '\0');
```

If I take the space out in front of the % in the scanf line, and user just hits enter, the computer goes into an infinite loop and just prints gook to the screen.  (The text on the screen is moving too fast for me to make sure, but I 'think' it is constantly printing the printf statement.)

With the space there, and the user just hits enter, it moves the cursor down to the next line until the user enters a valid string then moves on.

I want the question repeated every time the user just hits enter.  I have tried empty for(;;), while and here you see the do-while variation.

Any comments welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: IDR my C but I think you want `!=` and you're forcing the first letter to be a space so it would never exit. Maybe try strlen < 2 or remove the space

Comment: To help you see the output, you could redirect it to a text file.

Comment: @icbytes is that a sentence?

Comment: Should have been a thought.

Comment: My gut reaction is why rely on a complex API like scanf that requires you to learn its special syntax?
Yes it's full of features, but when it won't do what you want, sometimes it's simpler to just write some if statements and for loops.

Comment: It will also help if you try to explain what you are trying to do in words. I mean describe each step to make sure the logic you have in code is what you really want. You should also fire up a debugger or add some printf() calls to show the values of your variable. (Again, you can redirect to a file or pipe to `less` to help with the fast scrolling.)

Comment: @icbytes You should probably edit because the thought doesn't make much sense as you have written it.

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but I think this is extremely relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311156/how-do-i-use-scanf-to-accept-a-default-value-by-simply-pressing-enter-key

Comment: Store at location is done via & , isnt it?

Comment: @icbytes the array name (without subscripts) is already the address you want to pass to scanf. If you really want to use the address operator, would have to pass &string[0] (which is the same, but more cryptic).

Comment: Arghhh. If it was a single variable of char. Right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem without the space is that if the user just hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the scanf will fail (so nothing will be written to string), and NO INPUT WILL BE READ.  So the newline will still be on the input, which means that when you loop, it will immediately fail again giving you an infinite loop.

With the space, the scanf call will read and ignore whitespace (including newlines) without returning, so when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> it stay in the scanf.

The simplest solution is to just use fgets:

```
do {
    printf("Enter a text message (maximum 100 characters long) : ");
    if (!fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin)) {
        /* error or eof */
        exit(1); }
} while (string[0] == '\n');
```

But this does not ignore leading whitespace on the line and will accept a line consisting only of spaces.  If you want that, you'll need something like:

```
char *p;
do {
    printf("Enter a text message (maximum 100 characters long) : ");
    if (!fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin)) {
        /* error or eof */
        exit(1); }
    p = string + strspn(string, " \t"); /* skip over leading spaces and tabs */
} while (p[0] == '\n' || p[0] == 0);
```

One of the major limitations of `scanf` is that its not good at distinguishing between spaces and newlines -- it treats both a whitespace.

Comment: Works like a champ!  I was ready to pull my hair out when it made my check_palindrome() function stop working, but then I changed the end character search to '\n' instead of '\0' and started working like a charm!  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `fgets` rather than `scanf`, because for your purpose, you want
to deal with a line at a time, and the input might contain embedded whitespace.  You should check the user's input for trailing newlines and strip them (by replacing with `'\0'`).  Then your `while` condition should work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say better to use `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[101];
    int menu;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a text message (maximum 100 characters long) : ");
        fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    }while (string[0] == '\n');

}
```

You should note that `fgets` do not discard `\n` character and reads it. When you will press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `\n` will stored at `string[0]`. Therefore, you need to check `string[0] == '\n'`.

Comment: This will prompt again if the string is not empty, which is the opposite of what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It was your explanation about fgets not discarding the '\n' character that helped finish the program.  When I converted to the fgets statement, my check_palindrome() function quit working, but I was having it look for the '\0' as the end of the string.